# How to swap out to a new file a running process output is redirecting to, without restarting the command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a background process that I do not want to restart. Its output is actively being logged to a file.

```
nohup mycommand 1> myoutputfile.log 2>&1 &
```

I want to "archive" the file the process is currently writing its output to, and make it start writing to a blank file at the same file name. **I must be able to do this without having to kill the process and start it again.**

I tried simply renaming the existing file (to `myoutputfile_.log`), hoping that the shell now finding that the file is no longer there, will create a new file with the original file name (`myoutputfile.log`). But this does not work as the shell holds a reference to the file's location and keeps appending to it.

I looked [here](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/). On executing `ls`, I see that the streams are now marked as `(deleted)` but I'm quite confused what to do next. In the `gdb` command, do I have to specify the process executable in addition to the process ID? What happens if I don't specify it or I get it wrong? Once in `gdb`, how do I force the stream to re-create a file in the deleted file's same location (same path and filename)?

How can I use the commands in shell to signal it to start a new file for an existing process's output redirection?

*PS: I can't do a trial-and-error because it's rather important I get this right. If it is relevant to know, this is a `java` process.*

Comment: You seem to be looking for `logrotate`.

Comment: Interesting. Mind writing up answer with a basic **101** lesson on `logrotate` please? `:)`

Comment: @devnull But how can I do this on-the-fly without having to mess with configuration files and system setup? It seems to be for pre-configured schedule-based rotation.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you can indeed do this trial and error. Just set up another command printing to a different file and experiment on it.

Comment: Using [multilog](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) is yet another option.  Probably simpler than `logrotate`.

Comment: Hmm... I just `cp` the file to a backup and `echo >` into the original file. I did this in a single command line execution using `;` and it worked.

Comment: There is a reason why system tools use the system log facility rather than simple I/O redirection. A good number of reasons, actually. Anyway, just replace the redirection with a pipe to [`logger`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?logger+1) and the rest should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by doing the following:

```
cp myoutputfile.log myoutputfile_.log; echo > myoutputfile.log
```

This essentially reset the log file after copying the original contents to a new file.